Unable to install converters for openChrom when building in developer mode
I am currently exploring and working with openChrom, trying to extend the project by writing some plug-ins. I am following the development Quickstart guide on the official github page, and so far I was able to clone the repository and start the application. However, I was not able to fetch and install the converters, as everytime I try to do so, this error prompts up in the console:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Profile id _SELF_ is not registered.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.ProfileChangeRequest.createByProfileId(ProfileChangeRequest.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.InstallOperation.computeProfileChangeRequest(InstallOperation.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProfileChangeOperation.makeResolveJob(ProfileChangeOperation.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProfileChangeOperation.resolveModal(ProfileChangeOperation.java:115)
    at net.openchrom.installer.ui.discovery.PrepareInstallProfileJob.resolve(PrepareInstallProfileJob.java:125)
    at net.openchrom.installer.ui.discovery.PrepareInstallProfileJob.run(PrepareInstallProfileJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:124)

Heres a clearer picture
I am very new to RCP and has only started learning it because I want to extend openChrom to allow some extra functionality for my chromatography project. If you know anything around this issue please guide me, thanks!
I tried removing and adding projects and tweaking the product configurations, but didn't change anything.

You can't install plugins while running an RCP application via the IDE. There is a checkbox in the launch configuration to allow it, but it won't persist when you restart.
